# * coming in place of keys when connecting saiku with mongo using apache drill

Tags: mongodb, apache-drill, saiku

I am using Apache drill in embedded mode and when I am able to connect to mongo and query in drill successfully.

However when I create a schema in saiku schema designer using driver as "org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver" and URL as "jdbc:drill:drillbit=hostname:31010" the connection is successful and all collections are also fetched and shown as tables in saiku, but in place of column names "*" is coming and actual column names are not coming.

Dont know what I am missing on.

Comment: Can you share the code which is triggering the issue

Comment: I am creating schema using saiku schema designer GUI, not writing any separate code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution and posting in case anyone could benefit. I had created a view in drill with select * from table. When I created view as select col1,col2... from table the issue got resolved.